# system call searching for a file(C, minix)

Tags: c, file, search, system-calls, minix

I am working on a project on Minix 3.2.1
I need to create a new system call (on the vfs server) which will get a filename as a parameter(filename only! NOT path) and print the file's inode number.
how to implement the code that's relative on the file searching?
The filepath is unknown but needs to be retrieved in order to find the inode.
the search needs to be done on every directory.

thanks in advance :D

Comment: Sounds interesting, at which university are you?

Comment: Recursive `find` on root.

Comment: @Mike76 at CEID (uni of patras, greece)

Comment: @Mike76 any ideas?